# Счётчик строк Python

Tags: python

Как сделать счётчик который будет считать строки которые ввводятся на Pythone.
Пример:
Есть программа которая выводит в терминал различные слова
Привет
Дом
Книга
Дерево
Плита

Получается 5 слов, как сделать программу которая будет считать количество этих слов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: да хрен знает, как ее сделать. зависит от того, откуда эти слова берутся

Comment: @Эникейщик есть лист с этими словами, они в случайном порядке генерируются и выводятся, как сделать подсчёт их и вывести

Comment: запутанность вопроса начинается с того, что надо подсчитывать — строки или слова.

Comment: добавь в вопрос пример "листа с этими словами", объясни как они в случайном порядке генерируются и что там выводится. Тогда другие тоже может быть что-то поймут.

Comment: Скорее всего тут поможет метод `enumerate`

Comment: @CrazyElf в зависимости от того, что и откуда выводится, даже len() может помочь :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть простой вариант, если ты вводишь только 1 строку и в ней передаешь слова:

```
def count_words(string: str) -> int:
    s = string.strip(' ').replace('  ', ' ')
    if not s:
        return 0
    return s.count(' ') + 1
```

Как правило, это редкий кейс, чаще требуется получить список слов(всегда можно узнать его длину)

```
 def count_words(string: str) -> int: 
      return string.strip(' ').replace('  ', ' ').split()
```

Если нужно прочитать с потока ввода и посчитать все слова, то можно сделать так:

file test.py:

```
 import sys
 
 count = 0
 for line in sys.stdin:
     count += count_words(line)
```

shell:

```
 echo first second test | python3 test.py
```

Стоит добавить, что с точки зрения алгоритмов count_words не оптимальная функция, это просто быстрое решение на python.
Если делать оптимально, то потребуется всего 1 проход по строке, сравниваешь текущий символ и предыдущий, используя состояния.

Answer (score 0):

можно воспользоваться декоратором для подсчета числа вызовов print. Правда, он подсчитает все вызовы, независимо от содержания.

```
def call_counter(func):
    def _(x):
        _.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    _.calls = 0
    return _

print = call_counter(print)

for i in range(10):
    print('')

print(print.calls)  # 10
```

Или можно назвать декорированную функцию другим именем, myprint, например, и использовать ее для специальных данных.